# C# API for puppeteer

Tags: html, dom, html-rendering, puppeteer, getboundingclientrect

Is there any C# API for using Puppeteer?

Use case: need to get the coordinates/bounding box for HTML. Could have used Selenium + PhantomJS, but given the instability issues of PhantomJS, we want to try out Puppeteer.

Can someone please help?

Comment: What did you end up going with for a solution for this?

Answer (score 14):

Sharp puppeteer looks like a good new solution for c#

https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp

Based on Google Chrome puppeteer

Comment: Yes, that works fine!.
The API documentation is on https://www.puppeteersharp.com/

Answer (score -3):

Puppeteer is a Node.js client library for the Chrome DevTools protocol. A quick Google search found at least two different DevTools client libraries for C# (haven't tried either of those, though):

- https://github.com/MasterDevs/ChromeDevTools
- https://github.com/BaristaLabs/chrome-dev-tools-runtime

Comment: Both of these do not appear to be Puppeter APIs: